# Compare three excel columns to find the lowest number and highlight it

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have three excel columns containing different prices. I would like to run through these columns and find the lowest price and highlight it with a different cell colour or change its text colour.

Example:

```
  A1 -> 21,000
  B1 -> 3,000
  C1 -> 7,500
```

The cell to be highlighted would be **B1**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this which seems to work:

`=IF(A1<>"",IF(A1=MIN($A1:$C1),1,0),0)`

**Result:**
[image]

To apply it on the entire column, change the *Applies to* field to:

`=$A:$C`

[image]

HTH.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Although when I tried to compare between columns that are separate from each others (ex. A1, C1, E1). It didn't work. I suppose there is a simple way but I couldn't figure it out..

Answer (score 0):

You can use Conditional Formatting for this.

1. Set the condition as the 'Formula' option and use the condition
   of `=MIN(A1:C1)`
2. Set the conditional format to the desired
   highlighting settings.

Answer (score 0):

You could also write a little VBA script to determine the smallest Valeue in any Range.

Here is a link to with the necessary information:

[http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=105:find-smallest-and-largest-value-in-range-with-vba-excel&catid=79&Itemid=475](http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=105%3afind-smallest-and-largest-value-in-range-with-vba-excel&catid=79&Itemid=475)